# "Bad handshake method" error with socket-io

Tags: node.js, angular, websocket, socket.io

I use nodejs on the server side and angular 8 on the client side.
I'm looking to connect my backend and frontend with socket-io in addition to my standard http communication.

app.module.ts :

```
import { SocketIoModule, SocketIoConfig } from 'ngx-socket-io';
    
const config: SocketIoConfig = { url: 'http://localhost:3000', options: {transport : ['websocket'], withCredentials: true} };

#Then in imports of @NgModule:

    SocketIoModule.forRoot(config),
```

My component :

```
    import { Socket } from 'ngx-socket-io';
    
    @Component({...})
    export class AppComponent implements OnInit{
    
      ngOnInit(){
        this.socket.emit('setUsername', "Mathis");
      }
    
      constructor(
        private socket: Socket){}
   }
```

My back:

```
    const http = require('http');
    const app = require('./app');
    const cors = require('cors');
    
    const whitelist = ['http://localhost:4200'];
    const corsOptions = {
      credentials: true, // This is important.
      origin: (origin, callback) => {
        if(whitelist.includes(origin))
          return callback(null, true)
    
          callback(new Error('Not allowed by CORS'));
      }
    }
    const port = 3000
    app.set('port', port);
    app.use(cors(corsOptions));

const server = http.createServer(app);
const io = require('socket.io')(server, {
  cors: {
    origin: "http://localhost:4200",
    methods: ["GET", "POST"],
    credentials: true
  }
});
io.on("connection", socket => {
  console.info("connected")

  io.emit("file", {hello:"word"});
});

server.on('error', errorHandler);
server.on('listening', () => {
  
  const address = server.address();
  const bind = typeof address === 'string' ? 'pipe ' + address : 'port ' + port;
  console.log('Listening on ' + bind);
});

server.listen(port);
```

And when I throw :

[image]

that sends me back : `{"code":2,"message":"Bad handshake method"}`

And :
[image]

that sends me back :

[image]

I've done a lot of research but haven't found any answers to my problem. Any ideas?

Comment: Why don't you use a rxjs WebsocketSubect instead ?

Comment: I was following a tutorial but I tried to use it :

`import { webSocket, WebSocketSubject } from "rxjs/webSocket";

const subject = webSocket('ws://localhost:3000');
subject.subscribe();`

But it generates an error in the backend :

`Error: read ECONNRESET`